# Bitdefender acusando virus ao compilar fonte c++ com CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks, antivirus

Uso o Bitdefender há alguns anos, e CodeBlocks há algum tempo, e hoje especificamente os programas não estavam compilando, até que vi que o BitDefender estava acusando virus (**Gen:Variant.Symmi.86658**) em qualquer programa compilado, até mesmo num projeto novo com Hello World.

Fiz um boot scan com um boot recovery da BitDefender, mas ele não achou nada.
Entretanto continua o problema.

Minha dúvida é: **Será um falso positivo?** Devo desabilitar os programas gerados pelo CodeBlocks para não serem interceptados pelo BitDefender? Ou será que meu Windows está infectado de alguma forma invisível para o Bitdefender?

Também desativei o Bitdefender por uns minutos, gerei um .exe e submeti ao VirusTotal, que acusou um bocado de problemas:
https://www.virustotal.com/pt/file/ca86a72936301bb4199857fe4ed194eb6aaeb7d5dde1d3822c1e00acaec4763a/analysis/1526009068/

Comment: Fiz uma reparação do Bitdefender (desinstala e reinstala), atualizando todo o banco de dados de virus.
Isto resolveu o problema!